# what the difference between kill the webloigc pid and run the stopWeblogic.sh

Tags: linux, weblogic

in the linux os ,what is  the difference  between  kill the weblogic porcess and run the stopWeblogic.sh?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the contents of `stopWeblogic.sh` my assumption would be that the script shuts down the service gracefully, but killing the pid in the OS just kills it, ungracefully.

Perhaps post some code and the answer could be better suited to your particular case.